# Heroku scheduler Resque

Tags: heroku, cron, scheduler, resque, rake-task

I have a ruby on rails app (1.9.2 and 3.2) running on Heroku with Redis/Resque that requires a rake task be enqueued at regular intervals.  Right now I am running 'heroku run rake update_listings' from my local machine once or twice a day....I would like to automate this.  I've tried the whenever gem, but the task would not start up in the background.  Heroku scheduler seems like the appropriate solution, but I am confused by the scheduler.rb file.  I have:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task :hourly_feed => :environment do
  Rake::Task[update_listings].execute
end
```

When I ran the :hourly_feed task from the Heroku Scheduler console and checked heroku logs, I saw several web dynos get spun up by hirefireapp, but the update_listings rake task was never invoked.

Update: I gave up on resque_scheduler.  I am too green to make this work, so trying to use crontab and a sript file.  Here is my update.sh script file:

```
Rake::Task["update_listings"].execute
```

I set cron using crontab-e and I have it executed every 5 minutes, but I get an error in mail logs:

```
Projects/livebytransit/update.sh: line 1: Rake::Task[update_listings].execute: command not found
```

It appears it is finding my update.sh script file and reading it, but it is not executing the code.  I noticed the log entry dropped the quotes, so I also tried using single quotes in the shell script file, no change.  I also tried changing the update.sh to this:

```
heroku run rake update_listings
```

error came back `heroku: command not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the Heroku Scheduler works perfectly...I simply forgot the quotes around "updated listings".

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I used resque_scheduler, which will add jobs to the resque / redis queue using cron.

resque_schedule.yml

```
count_delayed_jobs_job:
 cron: "0 */1 * * *"
 class: Support::CountDelayedJobsResque
 queue: CDJ
 args: 
 description: "count_delayed_jobs_job, every 1hr"
```

alternatively, you could just chuck `Rake::Task["update_listings"].execute` in a shell script and use crontab to trigger the job.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with some issues I ran into attempting a crontab solution.

Comment: How is your procifle setup to do this @TomDunning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537142/heroku-procfile-resque-puma-rails-5-resque-scheduler-setup

Comment: @chrishough, to do what? Execute the scheduler? That's part of the resque_scheduler gem